# Android button size in a TableRow

Tags: android, button, layout

I'm read Andorid Metrics and Grids (http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html) and now im trying to make my layout looks good.
I've got TableRow with two elements TextEdit and button.

```
<TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow2" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/personDOB"
    android:hint="Date of birth"
    android:inputType="date" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/openCalendar"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/mybutton_background"
    android:contentDescription="@string/selectdate"
    android:cropToPadding="true"
    android:onClick="selectDate"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_datepicker"/>
</TableRow>
```

My button is 32x32 (so i can add margin 8dp each side for 48dp rhytm) but in TableRow it's like 3 times width.
I tried making button layout_width = 48dp (as above), wrap content, make some experiments with width=0px & weight but all this doesn't help.
I need by button to be fixed size and all other row space must be used by EditText.

Answer (score 1):

Replace following layout with your one.

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/personDOB"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="Date of birth"
        android:inputType="date" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/openCalendar"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/mybutton_background"
        android:contentDescription="@string/selectdate"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:cropToPadding="true"
        android:onClick="selectDate"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_datepicker" />
</TableRow>
```

Comment: as i mention above, width+weight params doesn't help here (i tried varied params for both TextEdit and ImageButton) - my button still too wide

Comment: @eXeLe, why you have taken `height=wrap_content` ?

Comment: I need somethink like this - http://imgur.com/LKIgci8 (made in relative layout, sorry for some russian text there)

Comment: I am removing my unnecessary comments to clean up :). Can you one more time add your `ic_datepicker` icon there.

Comment: @eXeLe can you try using width `32dp`

Comment: hmmm... 32dp was not that wide. i changed for 22dp and it works better.
i also tried 32px - works well too